# D3 lineRadial does not show while other elements do show

Tags: d3.js, line, radial

I have the following 'hand of a clock' implemented as a lineRadial. However, it does not show.
Why not?

```
const line = d3.select("svg")
    .append("lineRadial")
    .attr("angle", -Math.PI / 2)
    .attr("radius", 60)
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(60,60)");
```

I don't understand, I have other elements in the svg which work fine. Even another line (shown below) which works find. Any explanation? Is there any difference?

```
const line = d3.select("svg")
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", 0).attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", -60)
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineRadial` is not a valid svg component, you must say `line` (as in your second code snippet, also, `angle` is not a valid `line` attribute, you should say something like:

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
```

I would recommend to read the doc for rotate, as it takes 3 parameters. Here is an
explanation: `The rotate(<a> [<x> <y>]) transform function specifies a rotation by a degrees about a given point. If optional parameters x and y are not supplied, the rotation is about the origin of the current user coordinate system. If optional parameters x and y are supplied, the rotate is about the point (x, y).` from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

Finally, please note that the angle must be passed in degrees.

Comment: Thanks Guillermo, that sounds very reasonable what you say. I'll try it tomorrow and let you know the result! (so what I did was a kind of hybrid error trying to use a d3 function the wrong way).

Comment: Sure, let us know how it goes. I just noticed that in the first code snippet you are not setting the x1, x2, y1 and y2 , you will need them in order to draw the line.

Comment: That does the trick. Easy and logical when you think of it.
Thanks!!